# Android ObjectAnimator with radius

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Никак не могу разобраться с ObjectAnimator. Мне нужно изменить позицию объекта по окружности, где радиус 100:
[image: пр]

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball, "radius", 100F, 100F);
            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            set.play(animator);
            set.setDuration(3000);
            set.start();
```

"radius" - такого свойства нету, есть только стандартные - "rotation","translationX"... Как мне создать такое свойство? Или скиньте ссылку, где об этом рассказывается.

Comment: Так **Animation** не перемещает полностью объект, а только визуально. То есть если я его перемещаю с точки 0 в 200, кликнуть по нему в точке 200 не могу. Сущность его останется в  0.
**Rotate** поворачивает сам объект, а не передвигает его по окружности. Или я не правильно понял!

Answer (score 4):

Решил эту проблему с помощью класса `ValueAnimator` и математического уравнения x^2+y^2=r^2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `ValueAnimator` есть метод `addUpdateListene`, где я могу как получить координаты, так и засетить. Для траектории анимации нужно получать **y**, для этого нужен радиус, который я знаю и **х**, который могу брать методом `getAnimatedValue()`.

Потом пришлось играться с вычислением **х**, так как центр у меня был не в т.(0,0), а в т. (100,0). Поставил проверку, если **х <= r** и **r < x && x <= r*2**

```
private float x = 0f;
private float y = 0f;
private float radius = 100f;

ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0F, 2 * radius);
            animator2.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    x = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    Log.d("coordinate", "x = " + x);
                    float newX = 0;
                    if (x <= radius) {
                        newX = radius - x;
                        Log.d("coordinate", "newX = " + newX);
                    } else if (radius < x && x <= radius * 2) {
                        newX = x - radius;
                        Log.d("coordinate", "newX = " + newX);
                    }
                    y = (float) Math.sqrt(radius * radius - newX * newX);
                    Log.d("coordinate", "y = " + y);
                    ViewCompat.setTranslationX(ball, x);
                    ViewCompat.setTranslationY(ball, y);
                }
            });
            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            set.play(animator);
            set.setDuration(3000);
            set.start();
```